# Why are these variables "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have the folowing code :

```
var canvasData;
var canvas2imgval;

imageObj1.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0, wdOb1, hgOb1);
    imageObj2.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj2, imgposLeft, imgposTop, wdOb2, hgOb2);
        //img = c.toDataURL("image/png");
        //document.write('<img src="' + img + '" width="256" height="256"/>');
        //canvas2img
        canvasData = c.toDataURL("image/png");
    }

}
console.log("canvasData : "+canvasData ); 
$("#canvas2img").val(canvasData) ;
canvas2imgval = $("#canvas2img").val() ;
console.log("canvas2imgval1 : "+canvas2imgval );
```

The problem is when I view the value of both variables, `canvasData` is `undefined` and `canvas2imgval1` has no value.
I don't know what's wrong with my code. Normally those two variables are marked public with the JavaScript keyword `var`.

Comment: `canvasData = c.toDataURL("image/png");` What is `c`?

`canvas2imgval = $("#canvas2img").val() ;` Does that element exist?

Comment: You assign values to these variables in image onload event handlers, but try to access them before these handlers are executed.

Comment: you use these variable before imageObj1 is loaded. This is HTTP request, your browser will load HTML then javascript then other objects.

Comment: These two variables are not going to have values until imageObj1's onload event runs. If you are looking at their values immediately after assigning a function to imageObj1.onload, then they will be undefined.

Comment: the c variable it is the variable holding the canvas element that i want to merge on it my two images :

Comment: var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

Comment: You also shouldn't be assigning imageObj2's event handler inside the event handler for imageObj1. If imageObj2 loads first, then your code will never run.

Answer (score 1):

You assign values to these variables in image `onload` event handlers, but try to access them before these handlers are executed.

In order to use these variables you could create a function that will be called after `imageObj2.onload` executes. I'd also suggest to pass the `canvasData` as an argument instead of using a global variable (as long as it's not used elsewhere).

```
var canvas2imgval;
var afterLoad = function(canvasData){
    console.log("canvasData : "+canvasData ); 
    $("#canvas2img").val(canvasData) ;
    canvas2imgval = $("#canvas2img").val() ;
    console.log("canvas2imgval1 : "+canvas2imgval); 
}    

imageObj1.onload = function() {
ctx.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0, wdOb1, hgOb1);
    imageObj2.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj2, imgposLeft, imgposTop, wdOb2, hgOb2);
        //img = c.toDataURL("image/png");
        ////////document.write('<img src="' + img + '" width="256" height="256"/>');
        //canvas2img
        canvasData = c.toDataURL("image/png");
        afterLoad(canvasData);
    }

}
```