# javascript variable doesnt work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to get the width of an image but it it always undefine. here is the part of the code

```
var w;

var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var img = new Image();
img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
img.onload = function  () {
    w = this.width;
    console.log(w); // works
};

console.log(w); // undefined
```

and i notice the the last console log are being called first, and not the console inside a function(), is it the correct behavior? because i thought that it will call a function line by line.

if i input 4 files, the result will be 4 `undefined` first, then the actual width of the image.

Comment: onload is called asynchronously, when the image loads ... w will be undefined until that occurs, your code outside the onload function doesn't wait for the image to load

Comment: @JaromandaX so how can i get the value of this.width and use it outside the onload

Comment: simple answer, you can't, complex answer, learn how to use asynchronous code using either callbacks or promises

Comment: @markoverflow you need to use a callback. You can call functions inside the onload to use your width variable or just put stuff in the `onload`. You could alternatively just predict the image width based on how it is styled or what not (not sure what the use case is).

Comment: @markoverflow, technically w will _become_ defined.. you just have to wait until the image has finished loading

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call will help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these variables "undefined"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830523/why-are-these-variables-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript execute line by line. `img.onload` function also invoked when the image loaded that means it's asynchronous. but in the mean time `console.log(w);` executes as it's synchronous and not dependent on `img.onload` function.If you declare `w` variable at first then it would not print `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is asynchronous and you cannot call `console.log(w)` outside the onload

`onload` func will execute asynchronously

http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/03/14/wrapping-your-head-around-async-programming/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var w;//Global variable (avoid this)
    
    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=8c1c8cba242e';
    img.onload = function  () {
        w = this.width;
        console.log('inside function:'+w); // works
    };
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img)
    console.log('outside function:'+w); // Because this happens before the onload function get called
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`img.onload = fun...` just register the function to the load event and pass for the next instruction. The function is called when the load event is emitted, that's after the later `console.log(w)` been executed with `undefined` value of `w`. You should read about **Syncronous** and **Asynchronous** calls.